# Cant connect to aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an ec2 instance and set the security group such that it is open for all ip but when i try to access the instance via public ip or dns i get the following error :

```
This site can’t be reached

ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com refused to connect.
```

My inbound rules :

[image: Inbound rules]

Comment: How are you connecting? `ssh`? Is the `ssh` server running on EC2 and listening on port 22? What is the output of the command `ssh -v ......`? What linux distro is the EC2 machine?

Comment: `refused to connect` is never caused by a security group issue.  It can't be. Security groups don't refuse (active), they discard (passive) resulting in a `timed out` error.  Your error means the service isn't running, or is bound to 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0, or is not listening on the intended port.  It looks like you're trying to access a web service.  Is that right?  Is it http? https? Custom port or standard?

Comment: AWS has a helpful page on diagnosing connectivity issues to EC2 instances: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes i want to access the web service, i plan to run a my sql rds instance on it, i have tried the trouble shooting mechanism in aws troubleshooting page but nothin works for me

Comment: There's nothing to troubleshoot from the AWS infrastructure perspective. This issue is inside your server.  Your web server process is not running, or not correctly configured. Try `netstat -a -n | grep ':80'`.  Report what you observe.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot grep is recognised so i used netstat -abon findstr portno to find the process running on port 80 , turns out it was httpd.exe but even killing the process didn't help

Comment: Oh, Windows.  Well, yeah, killing it wasn't the thing to do. Start it up and verify that it's listening on 0.0.0.0:80, not 127.0.0.1:80.  Verify that the Windows firewall is allowing traffic.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it runs on 0.0.0.0:8

Comment: Not 80?  That sounds like it could be the problem.

Comment: oh sorry its  0.0.0.0:80 my bad